# Custom BLE service with SPP support?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, mfi

I'd like to have bluetooth module with iOS support and Rx/Tx pins. iOS devices support only `MFI`-certified Bluetooth 2.1 modules (and i can't find any) or BLE modules. But most BLE modules do not have Rx/Ts pins for transparent interaction.

As possible solution #1 Adafruit [created board based on `nRF8001` bt chip](https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/adding-app-support) with custom BLE service with 1 characteristics for Rx and 1 characteristics for Tx and but unfortunately it supports SPI only and i need direct Rx/Tx pins to be wired to Arduino board directly. That needs Arduino sketches modification to work over SPI instead of `Serial` class and that's bad.

Also i've found solution #2 from Sparkfun [based on `BC118` chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13019). It seems to have custom BLE service too but with SPP support! But it's comparably expensive and not widespread.

**The question is**:

how to develop custom BLE service with direct Rx/Tx pin for [widespread `cc2540`/`cc2541` and cheap chips](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xcc2540%20bluetooth%20module.TRS0&_nkw=cc2540%20bluetooth%20module&_sacat=0)? Are there any hardware limitations/requirements for it?

Comment: core Bluetooth only supports GATT profile so you are going to need some smarts in the BLE chip to take the serial data and expose it as an attribute value (and vice versa). The LightBlue Bean isn't cheap either but it has the Arduino on board

Comment: right, any existing firmware/source code? or existing bt modules suitable for requirements

Comment: Besides the Bean?  If you have high volumes and can handle surface mount you can get the BLE module from the Bean for about $10

Comment: oh, no. i'm just software developer and i need minor modifications that my ios app users can do with their bt modules. The most i can do is to try to create bt custom service and let people upload it to their bt modules or suggest existing bt module

Comment: The Bean is about the same price as the spark fun module you linked to but includes an Arduino, accelerometer the BLE chip and has a full iOS library. What exactly are you trying to do with the BLE module?

Comment: i need to have "wireless serial" between iOS device and arduino (with no arduino sketch modifications). at the  moment i think i should create custom service to "talk" to arduino over UART (arduino `Serial` class). Can u give link to the product you suggest please? Though it's better to have BT module instead of whole system in 1 board

Comment: https://punchthrough.com/bean/

Comment: thanks for the useful link! I should read more as i was trying to recreate pretty the same but with few separated modules: BT + arduino. I'm still interested in any suggestions though

Comment: There is also the BLE mini from RedBear Labs - I haven't used their products but I have seen positive reports from others - http://store.redbearlab.com/products/blemini It is almost as much as a Bean however.

Comment: The HM-10 should do what you want - http://www.fasttech.com/products/0/10004051/1292002-ti-cc2540-bluetooth-40-ble-2540-transparent-serial

Comment: since it's based on cc2540/cc2541 i'm not sure it's "Transparent Serial" as it's written in the title. BLE does not support SPP and i can't see Rx/Tx pins on the board. This makes me think that guys did not create their BT service with SPP emulation to make it "Transparent Serial"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71750/discussion-between-paulw11-and-4ntoine).